# Smart-table clearing table rows and headers when I close a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, smart-table

I'm using Angular-Smart-table to generate a table full of events for a project.

Adding and removing columns is a requirement, and we have a separate UI component for doing so. This UI component is a modal, and it's a checkbox of the columns I want to include. When this modal closes however, my smart-table goes blank and doesn't update with new choices when I update the table column headers.

Here is the code in the controller that handles the tablesettings event.

```
 function activate(){
        vm.$on('tablesettings', function(event, args){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(args);
                vm.tableColumns = {};
                angular.forEach(args.columns, function(v,k){
                    vm.tableColumns[v.value] = v.label;
                });
                vm.tableRows = [];

                addTabletoScope(TableService.cache.data);
            },30000)


        });

    }


    function addTabletoScope(td){
        vm.tableRows = [].concat(vm.tableData);
        console.log(vm.tableColumns);
    }
```

Here is the HTML for the table:

```
    <div class="gTable" style="overflow-x:auto; height:100%;">
<table style="width: 100%" st-table="tableRows" st-safe-src="tableData" st-pipe="tableControl.getPages()" st-pagination-scroll class="table table-striped scroll">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in tableColumns">{{val}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableRows">
        <td >{{row.eventDateString}}</td>


        <td >{{row.cocom}}</td>
        <td >{{row.country}}</td>
        <td >{{row.province}}</td>
        <td >{{row.district}}</td>
        <td >{{row.iedType}}</td>
        <td >{{row.incidentType}}</td>
        <td>{{row.eventId}}</td>



       <!-- <td ng-hide="cityremove">{{row.city}}</td>-->

    </tr>


    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
            <div  st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="pageNumbers" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
    </div>
```

Here's where I broadcast the tablesettings event,

```
function handleWidgetSettingsReturn(response) {
            switch (response.widgetType) {
                case "chart": {
                    if (!angular.isUndefined(response.widgetSubType) &&
                        response.widgetSubType !== scope.item.settings.widgetSubType) {
                        scope.item.settings.widgetSubType = response.widgetSubType;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "table": {
                    if (!angular.isUndefined(response.widgetOptions)) {
                        $log.info("Table settings set");
                        scope.item.settings.widgetOptions = response.widgetOptions;
                        console.log(scope.item.settings.widgetOptions);
                        scope.$broadcast('tablesettings', scope.item.settings.widgetOptions);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is where the modal instance is closed on ok.

```
function ok() {
        var result = {
            widgetType: $scope.widgetConfig.widgetType,
            widgetSubType: ($scope.widgetConfig.getWidgetSubtype())? $scope.widgetConfig.getWidgetSubtype() : undefined,
            widgetOptions: ($scope.widgetConfig.generateWidgetOptions())? $scope.widgetConfig.generateWidgetOptions() : undefined
        };

        $modalInstance.close(result);
```

It feels like my template doesn't come back and isn't refreshing or changing, even when I update the scope.tableColumns with the modal response. $scope.apply() also does not work for me, nor a refresh method.

I'm not sure why my smart-table goes blank when I hit ok for that modal.

Comment: A demo would help. Not sure why you have a 30 second timeout and should probably be using `$timeout`

Comment: That was a check initially to see whether it was going to my controller. I changed it to 1000 seconds just recently, and use $timeout.

Comment: The project itself is also massive and has a lot of different required components so putting them all into a demo is a bit difficult.

Comment: don't see why creating a scaled down demo that replicates problem would be difficult